# gspread api getting 500 internal error with get requests only , I can update cells but can't read

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a gspread project that reads and updates multiple sheets daily
suddenly one of the sheets I can update but can't read and getting

APIError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}

I get this with only (get , get_batch) functions
like :

worksheet.findall('str_example')

worksheet.acell('A1')

### here's the error msg :

APIError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 cells= worksheet.findall(str_example)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/worksheet.py in findall(self, query, in_row, in_column, case_sensitive)
1717         :rtype: list
1718         """
-> 1719         return list(self._finder(filter, query, case_sensitive, in_row, in_column))
1720
1721     def freeze(self, rows=None, cols=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/worksheet.py in _finder(self, func, query, case_sensitive, in_row, in_column)
1634
1635     def _finder(self, func, query, case_sensitive, in_row=None, in_column=None):
-> 1636         data = self.spreadsheet.values_get(absolute_range_name(self.title))
1637
1638         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/spreadsheet.py in values_get(self, range, params)
179         """
180         url = SPREADSHEET_VALUES_URL % (self.id, quote(range))
--> 181         r = self.client.request("get", url, params=params)
182         return r.json()
183

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py in request(self, method, endpoint, params, data, json, files, headers)
84             return response
85         else:
---> 86             raise APIError(response)
87
88     def list_spreadsheet_files(self, title=None, folder_id=None):

APIError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}

Comment: What kind of data is the sheet holding or can you share a sample? Does the error still happen if you create a copy of it? A 500 error can be an issue in Google's servers, in which case you'd have to wait, or it could be something related to the contents of the sheet, since it only happens with GET.

Comment: Thanks , Apparently it was with google servers , but it took 2 days to get fixed, before I tried anything today I just run the same code , and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something with Google servers , as after 2 days everything worked fine with me changing the code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).